# spliting a string by space and dot and comma at the same time

Tags: java, android, string, split

How can I split a string by space, dot and comma at the same time? I want to get rid of them and get words only.

My code for space:

```java
str=array.get(0).split(" ");
```

After advices i wrote this

```java
 str=array.get(0).split("[ ]|[.]|[,]|[ \t]");
```

> > but i see a new problem

[String](https://i.hizliresim.com/yGWkPN.png)

[New problem](https://i.hizliresim.com/od5J2R.png)

Comment: Give example input and output

Comment: Split on a space, dot and comma using a character class `[ .,]`

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the empty string problem. See if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) can be used with a Regex pattern, so you can match more elaborated cases to split your string.

A matching pattern for your case would be:

```
[ \.,]+
```

Regex Exaplanation:
**[** .,**]**+ - The brackets create Character Set, that will match any character in the set.
[ .,]**+** - The plus sign is a Quantifier, it will match the previous token (the character set) one or more times, this solves the problem where the tokens are following one another, creating empty strings in the array.

You can test it with the following code:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello, World!, StackOverflow. Test Regex";
    String[] split = str.split("[ .,]+");
    for(String s : split){
      System.out.println(s);
    }    
  }
}
```

The output is:
Hello
World!
StackOverflow
Test
Regex

Answer (score 3):

Using `.split()` can lead to having empty entries in your array.

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String text = "This is... a real sentence, actually.";

Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher m = reg.matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```